# Database in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i am developing application in blackberry which use database. 
i want to make generalize class for that just like DBadepter class in android which have all operation to perform for database. if any one have solution for that then send to me.

thanx.

Answer (score 0):

you can also used persistence store for database check [this link](http://blackberrytutor.info/tutorials/37-general/49-persistent-storage)

it is easy compare to sqlite